# Eloquent - Excluding specific rows

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

Is it possible to exclude specific rows using eloquent?

I'd like to exclude rows using an array of post ids from query #1 in query #2.

Comment: To clarify, I can do this with one id like this:Post::where('id', '<>', '25');

Comment: But can't figure out the syntax or way to do this with an array of ids...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `whereNotIn`:

```
Post::whereNotIn('id', array(1, 7, 21))->get();
```

You can check the [Laravel Query Builder Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects) to get a better understanding of it's capabilities.

Comment: This is exactly what I need! I don't know how I missed it in the documentation... thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `except` for excluding specific rows as below:

```
Post::all()->except([1,2,4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this one [`makeHidden()`](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_makeHidden) on Collection.

My example is as follows:

```
//In Repository
public function getAdminPermissions(int $user_id): Collection
{
    return $this->model->where('user_id',$user_id)->get();
}

//In Service function
...
/** @var UserAdminRepository $userAdminRepository */
$userAdminRepository = app(UserAdminRepository::class);
$adminPermissionsCollection = $userAdminRepository->getAdminPermissions($data['user_id']);
if ($adminPermissionsCollection->isEmpty()) {
    throw new EmptyDatasetException("User with ID {$data['user_id']} does not have any data in corresponding table");
}
$adminPermissionsCollection->makeHidden(['user_id','created_at','updated_at']);
```

There are numerous approaches to this actually, one of the other possible ones is that you use [Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections) and leverage the `toArray` function

Also another one is if you are depending explicitly on the Eloquent Model you can use `$hidden` property on the Model class itself. [Reference $hidden property](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)